# Can't Set Custom Line Colors Using R TSstudio::ts_plot

Tags: r, plot, colors

Here's the code for a line chart with four variables I have created. It works, but the colors won't change as I've specified in the color attribute. I've also tried %>%ing the output to the layout function, to no avail.

```
ts_plot(ts_methane, 
    color = c("#c1dbf2", "#57bcd5", "#cbd5c6", "#8b9188"), 
    title = "Average Hourly Measurements",
    Xtitle = "Date/Time",
    Ytitle = "Value", 
    slider = TRUE, 
    line.mode =  "lines+markers", 
    Xgrid = TRUE,
    Ygrid = TRUE
    )
```

Please make a suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.